# C pointers and structures

Tags: c, pointers, struct

Can somebody please explain to me what the following code does.

```
set_element *p = (set_el*)malloc(sizeof(set_el)); 

p->value = elem;
p->next = NULL;

return p;
```

where `elem` is the element passed to the method in the parameter and I also have this:

```
 typedef struct set_el
 {
   int value;
   struct set_el* next;
 } set_el;
```

Comment: This site is pretty good in explaining c gibberish:-) http://cdecl.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like an implementation of a [linked list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linked_list).

`struct set_el` defines a node in the linked list where

- `value` holds the `int` data in a node.
- `next` is a pointer(link) to the next node in the list.

Memory is allocated for a new node to be added in the linked list:

```
set_el *p = malloc( sizeof *p ); // cleaned up according to @JohnBode's comment

// If malloc fails, log and return
if(p == NULL)  
{                   
    // log and take necessary action.
    return NULL;
}
```

Variable `elem` is copied to the data part(i.e. `value`) in the node:

```
p->value = elem;
```

Node `p` has no next node i.e. no outgoing link:

```
p->next = NULL;
```

Pointer to the newly created node is returned to the caller:

```
return p;
```

Comment: Note that the call to `malloc` can be cleaned up a bit: `set_el *p = malloc( sizeof *p );`.  The cast is not necessary (unless you're using a pre-1989 implementation), and can actually be counterproductive.

Comment: @JohnBode I just copied OP's code to add an explaination but no harm to clean it up. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

This code

- allocates memory just to hold one `set_el` structure
- set new `set_el` structure value to the passed element
- set the next pointer to `NULL`

In general it just prepend new `set_el` element to the one way linked-link list.